# Capturing Firefox network logs with Selenium WebDriver using Java

Tags: java, selenium

Is there a way to capture network logs while running an automated test on Firefox?
I tried to use

```
LogEntries logs = driver.manage().logs().get(LogType.BROWSER);
```

This does not work.

Comment: I get this error`Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: H. Last 1 characters read: H`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "FFLogs.txt");
```

After refreshing the project folder, we shall get the FFLogs.txt file where the logs shall be captured.

***OR.... Follow the official docs***

**Official Docs**: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/TraceLogs.html

Here's the Java example in the documentation above. You can specify the logging level by including it in the `.setLogLevel` method of `FirefoxOptions` class.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setLogLevel(FirefoxDriverLogLevel.TRACE);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

You can refer to the documentation for the different levels of `logging`.

Comment: I tried doing that but but it's not working for me , i will try tu use browsermobproxy

Answer (score 1):

you can use:    `System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "FFLogs.txt");` After refreshing the project folder, we shall get the FFLogs.txt file where the logs shall be captured.